# Issue With Receiving Keycloak Email to the Clients

Tags: authentication, keycloak, registration, keycloak-services, keycloak-connect

I have a fully functional Keycloak setup with verify email and then update password features enabled. I have tested multiple times and the mail sending part is working perfectly. But some clients reporting that they didn't receive the registration mail. This maybe due to their firewall, spam filter and so on, now I want way to check whether the email has sent from my system or not. Logs won't help at all, cannot find anything related to sent mails in logs.